# How to control Windows 7 snap feature with two monitors?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

There is an [Aero Snap](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/e7/2009/03/17/designing-aero-snap/) feature in Windows 7. However, it seems to not work when dragging a window to the edge that is adjoined to the second monitor. How to make it work properly? Maybe some `regedit` modification or something?

Answer (score 338, accepted):

You should use only **[keyboard shortcuts](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/487-snap-window-side.html)** for that configuration, since mouse movements alone seems not supported for that special side that crosses over to the other monitor.

> NOTE: On multiple monitors, continually pressing a keyboard shortcut combination below will cause the window to snap to the side and scroll in that direction through the multiple monitor screens.
>
> - <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>
>     This will snap the current window to the left side of the screen, or unsnap a window that is snapped to the right side of the screen.
> - <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>
>     This will snap the current window to the right side of the screen, or unsnap a window that is snapped to the left side of the screen.

Comment: It might be worth it to point out the Windows+Shift+[Left/Right] combination. This will keep the position on your monitor while switching the window between monitors.

Comment: Also, to quickly maximize a window, press Win+Up. To restore to a window, press Win+Down.

Comment: Another (mouse based) window snap - for any arbitrarily-sized window which is not maximised, hover on the top or bottom edge and double click to extend to the full height of the monitor while maintaining the width. (if you miss the top edge and click the title bar it goes maximised like any older version did, you need the double-headed arrow you would normally use for a resize drag action)

Comment: Very cool tip Ryan, hadn't found that yet; thanks! +1

Comment: Its sad that is not supported by using the mouse only. Does anyone know a solution by using a third party application? WinSplit and MaxTo doesn't allow that, too. Both need keyboard + mouse. I found "Dual Display Mouse Manager" that adds a delay crossing the screens. Like that + snapping would be perfect.

Comment: @AdamV Yet another mouse based window snap: Hover on any corner, you see the diagonal resize cursor. Drag to touch the top (or bottom) edge of screen and release. Same effect but you can also change the width at the same time.

Comment: @Alvin - nice one. I like that the window that creates can be at an arbitrary position (depending if you drag a left corner or right) and width, yet Win + Down Arrow still restores it to last size and position.

Comment: @AdamV: mouse-based, or win+shift+up.

Comment: @mgutt: DisplayFusion snaps to monitor edges (even if there is another adjacent monitor). The window does not get height-maximized though.

Answer (score 17):

For what it's worth there is a useful tool which runs on Windows called [WinSplitRevolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/) (*) which offers further window management features, including the ability to 'throw' windows to the left/right monitor or to resize windows to the left hand side, centre, top, right of the screen and etc. I find the Windows 7 default keys useful, this tool is much more comprehensive though.

(*) Later edit, unfortunately this tool is no longer being actively maintained, see the website for details.

Comment: +1 this is by far the best and most customisable tool for large/multi monitor setups, however there's no version compiled for 64bit win7 :(

Comment: @Andy: There may not be a Win7 x64 binary for download, the x86 one works just fine on my 64bit Win7 setup.

Comment: Wow, it should be the answer really. Very-very useful program thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[MaxTo](http://maxto.net/) now contains a [snap-to-window feature](http://maxto.net/versions#chapter-1) for Windows 7, as well as being a superb general window manager.

> Version 2010.12
>
> Released December 17th 2010.
>
> New features
>
> Windows snap to other windows, monitor
> edges and regions. Disabled by
> default.

As of 2021 January, MaxTo costs €29 for a lifetime personal license and €19/user/year for a business license.

Comment: This "snap" is only a movement of the window and does not resize the window. It won't work in the middle of two monitors, too.

Comment: @mgutt here's a video demonstrating the resizing between areas https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E15_e-f3hMg&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Thank you, but its not really comfortable to use the keyboard.

Comment: @mgutt keyboard shortcuts aren't mandatory ;) http://maxto.net/using

Comment: You need to press shift to resize the window automatically to a region or you need to move the window first to that region, release the window and click on the maximise button. Ok then you don't need the keyboard, but sorry, this can't be more complicate. Look how AquaSnap/WindowSpace works: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79OXjkVsf4U You don't need to use the keyboard AND you don't need to click multiple times. Simply move the window to a corner or side as it is done usually in windows. This is how it should work + Keyboard Shortcuts like in WindowSpace. Look my answer to this question.

Comment: IMHO MaxTo really shines on very large monitors with complex layouts and workflows: dev; ops; CAD. Shift key **not** necessary for maximise to region, please refer to above links.

Comment: As I said. You are able to use the mouse only, but you have to move the window first and after that you need to click on the maximizing icon. This are two steps. With Windows, AquaSnap, WindowSpace you have only one step (moving to one screen side). Ok very large monitors.. maybe 4k. My 2.5k doesn't need it as my mouse pointer is fast enough.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use Keyboard shortcuts (Windows Key + Arrow Left/Right) and/or you want to be more flexible (e.g. 4 windows per screen), there are two options to Snap-Resize through your mouse:

**AquaSnap** (<s>$9,-</s> $14,- per user)

http://www.nurgo-software.com/products/aquasnap

Cons:

- no delay crossing if you move a window between two monitors (so you need to move very slow to target the correct one)

Since 2014 all these cons are not present anymore:

- <s>it lacks the feature to disable the restoring of a window size after it is moved again</s>
- <s>I've mailed the developer some suggestions (02/2013), he answered fast and promised to realize them, but the project seems to be dead.</s>
- <s>a maximised window can't be moved (the windows 7 built-in feature is able to do that)</s>
- <s>does not support keyboard shortcuts</s>

and

**WindowSpace** ($24,95 per user)

http://www.ntwind.com/software/windowspace.html

Cons:

- the preview frame is under the moved window, sometimes the window is bigger, so you don't know if the window will be half or quarter size of the screen (not a huge issue)
- no delay crossing if you move a window between two monitors (so you need to move very slow to target the correct one)
- I've contacted the developer as well (23.11.2013), but I didn't get an answer by now.
- a maximised window can only be moved if the "restore old size" option is enabled

**General**

It is possible to get the delay crossing of multiple monitors through Dual Display Mouse Manager:
http://ddmm.sourceforge.net/

But this app has some bugs:

- problems if you switch on a monitor after windows has been started
- problems if you wake up the pc
- it is to complicate to use Ctrl + ~ with a non english keyboard to bypass the delay crossing (and it is not possible to overwrite the hotkey)

As you see there is no perfectly working app available. At the moment I hope WindowSpace will solve this problems as it seems to be the most active project. After that it will be perfect, but of course, expensive.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a docked toolbar on the inner seam of a multi-monitor setup then you will be able to use the half-monitor snap feature on that monitor when you hover over the toolbar. I use [Trillian Astra Instant Message program](http://www.trillian.im/download/) with the right dock setting and am able to snap to half the screen when I hover over the toolbar. If you had two toolbars, one on each side of the seam then you would be able to use the snap feature on both sides of both monitors. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/98863/aero-snap-on-a-multi-monitor-system/112226#112226) for more info.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you like Expose, you can use [Switcher](http://insentient.net/).  It is more customizable than Expose and works great on Win7.

Comment: The website in the link above no longer has anything to do with the Switcher app, and is now a landing page to sell stuff.  If anyone has a current official URL for Switcher, please do update this answer.