# How to dock a window to an inside edge of a dual-monitor setup

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to control Windows 7 snap feature with two monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/1093/how-to-control-windows-7-snap-feature-with-two-monitors)

I have a dual monitor setup at work. I am running Windows 7 Ultimate, and I would like to take advantage of the docking feature, whereby you can drag a window to the side of the monitor and have it expand and fill to half the screen. Trouble is, I would like to drag it to the inside edge(adjoining the other screen) and it does not activate.

How would I go about activating this for the inside edge?

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/1093/how-to-control-windows-7-snap-feature-with-two-monitors

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This behavior is by design.

On a dual monitor setup, the inside edges where the 2 monitors meet must be transparent for the 'snap' feature when dragging windows. If it were not transparent, you would not be able to drag anything from one monitor to the other monitor.

They thought that would be jarring experience.  But you can do it with the keyboard:

Click whatever program you want to dock, then press Windows+Arrow (right or left).

Comment: +1, I love the new shortcuts they put for dual monitors. I do Windows+Shift+Arrow a lot to move my windows between monitors

Comment: I know so many little shortcuts that they never want us to know about

Comment: The design didn't take into account monitors of different resolutions, where it **is** an edge to bump into.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using the windows+arrow keys, I highly suggest trying out [GridMove](http://jgpaiva.dcmembers.com/gridmove.html).  It's a fantastic window management program if you have multiple monitors (or even one large one).

Comment: +1 because gridmove is great, I had some nice custom grids I used to use. Snap is not so good, but I find it good enough, and the shortcut keys make a big difference

Answer (score 0):

Since i can't edit questions on SU.com, i'll post my question addendum here:

[image]

Notice the "edge" on the left side of the primary monitor, as well as on the top, right, and bottom of the primary monitor.

It's a bug that i caught immediately in RC, that's still in RTM.

Comment: Although the "virtual" desktop might be lined up across the bottom, your physical monitors may be lined up at their top edges (or vice versa), so although your mouse will bump against this edge, it might not be a "natural" feeling experience.
I used to use http://www.12noon.com/displaychanger.htm to set up resolution and offset for my laptop screen and external display so that the virtual and physical overlap regions lined up and my mouse appeared to travel in a straight line from one to the other without a vertical jump. Very useful tool.
Anyway, shortcut keys for snap are better than mouse.

Comment: In my case the logical setup matches the physical setup. i tried, and failed, to make windows dock against the left edge of my primary monitor (where i know there is an edge).  i assume it was an overlooked use-case at Microsoft.