# How to dock a window to an inside edge of a dual-monitor setup without a Windows key?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, windows-key, aero-snap, docking

I have read [other posts](https://superuser.com/questions/147642/how-to-dock-a-window-to-an-inside-edge-of-a-dual-monitor-setup?rq=1) about how to use the Windows key and the left/right arrow to dock a window against the right or left side of your screen.

My question is how does one perform that command with a keyboard that does not have a Windows key?

Comment: What Windows are you using? Also, whats wrong with just using the mouse?

Comment: @Victor You can't use a mouse to snap to the inside edge of a multi-monitor setup (unless you know of a way I don't?)

Comment: There is no alternative to the Windows key; you need to look at mapping a replacement to the (missing) Windows key.  See the proposed duplicate for suggestions.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 what about AdamVs or Alvin Wongs comment here: http://superuser.com/questions/1093/how-to-control-windows-7-snap-feature-with-two-monitors

Comment: @Victor I can't seem to locate any comments where they say anything about using a mouse to snap to an inside edge?