# How to reset AeroSnap to correct monitor size

Tags: windows-7, windows, aero-snap

I have dual monitors on Windows 7. Sometimes AeroSnap uses a wrong monitor size on my first monitor and windows then snap to about two third of my screen when try to snap to the right screen border. It is *not* the size of my second screen either. Booting helps, but I want to fix this without having to boot.

How can I reset AeroSnap to the correct monitor size?

Comment: Check this link and review it http://www.optimizingpc.com/windows7/startmenu_desktop_taskbar_w7.html

Comment: No, I try to snap to the right screen border and the window snaps to an virtual border at about 2/3 of my screen width.

Comment: @try this http://superuser.com/questions/1093/how-to-control-windows-7-snap-feature-with-two-monitors/1144#1144

Comment: No, same problem when I try the keyboard shortcuts.